# Installing Ruby on Rails in windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I saw some ruby tutorials today and like to learn it. The problem is that i'm stuck with the installation process! :(

I can't get a clear picture on how to install RoR. For example, to write php code i installed wamp and straight away started writing php scripts. And i'm using Dreamweaver CS4 as an IDE.

Can anyone enlighten me :

1) the process of installing RoR?

2) an IDE for RoR

3) What are gems? are they modules?

thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE: (2011-11-05)**

RubyInstaller is now mature and IS the preferred way to do the install: http://rubyinstaller.org/

SQLite can be installed normally too.

**Original post: (2010-01-25)**

The best way to start is using the one-click installer. I advise using the older installer ( http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/47082/ruby186-27_rc2.exe ) instead of the new RubyInstaller, because the latter is still a bit immature. While installing select rubygems support and the add ruby to the PATH option, to ease access to ruby binaries.

After installing (takes a while), fire a console, and install rails (and a database connector, like sqlite3) using the commands

```
gem install rails
gem install sqlite3-ruby –version=1.2.3
```

(the 1.2.3 version of the sqlite3 gem will work on windows correctly)

As you have guessed correctly gems are modules to ruby, and ruby on rails is one of these modules.

Now you have installed both ruby and rails, fire up a console, and type

```
rails applicationname
```

to create your first rails application. From here on read the tutorials and documentations.

Rails doesn't really need an IDE for development, you can use any decent text editor, but there are rails plugins for IDEs like eclipse, and editors like vim or emacs.

Comment: thanks a lot for the information. Is it ok to use ruby 1.86 version instead of 1.9?

Comment: stick to 1.8.x versions for the time being. Switch to 1.9.x if you already know the differences.

Comment: The comment was that the Ruby Eclipse installation instructions in the original post were outdated, see more recent info in my answer.

Comment: Rails 3.2 is the last one that supports Ruby 1.8. Ruby 1.8.6 and earlier are not supported, neither is version 1.9.1. So it's better to install Ruby 1.8 with Rails 3.2
Visit the following for more details: http://rubyonrails.org/download

Answer (score 0):

Answering on the IDE part: Besides a good plain text editor (vim and emacs have been suggested already), I found the [netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) IDE to work really well, especially on Windows.

Comment: I want to use Eclipse. Is it OK? or, is netbeans OK?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://railsinstaller.org) page works fine and installs on Windows recent releases (mid-2011) of the entire toolset:

1. Ruby 1.9.2-p290,
2. Rails 3.1, Git 1.7.6,
3. Sqlite 3.7.3.

Ruby **Eclipse** support is [here](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates/)

Configure to use it in *Window/Preferences/Ruby/Interpreters/Add (RailsInstaller Windows default is C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.2\bin\ruby.exe)*

1. Create File/New/Project/Ruby/Ruby Project and
2. add File/New/Empty Ruby Script.
3. type `puts "Hello, Ruby"` and
4. click Run and select Ruby Script.

Read the Console and enjoy.

Comment: BTW, the last version of NetBeans to support Ruby is 6.9.1 http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/6.9.1/final/bundles/netbeans-6.9.1-ml-ruby-windows.exe